# Renew STS credentials for dynamodb during scan operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

I'm new to python and need to migrate data from one dynamo db into another.
the problem is that we have multiple accounts for different environments for example one for dev and one for prod. I have/use Ec2 instance to migrate this data. To access prod account I have STS.

```
stsCredentials = boto3.client('sts').assume_role(
    RoleArn=STS_ROLE_TO_ACCESS_DEV_ACCOUNT_ARN,
    RoleSessionName='cross-account-dynamodb-role',
    DurationSeconds=STS_TOKEN_TIME_OUT
)

prodAccount = boto3.client(
    'dynamodb',
    region_name=AWS_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id=stsCredentials['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=stsCredentials['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=stsCredentials['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)
devAccount = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=AWS_REGION)
```

Then I need to scan production table(in reality I create backup and restored another table from this backup to reduce impact on prod table)

```
paginator = prodAccount.get_paginator('scan')
pageIterator = paginator.paginate(
    TableName=backupTableName,
    Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL',
    ConsistentRead=False
)
for page in pageIterator :
    for item in page['Items']:
        // Process response, store data to different files and migration to dev account
```

And the problem is that my prod db has too much data and STS token expires too quickly(Because of some restrictions I can not create sts credentials for more than 1 hour). As a result my pageIterator throws exception at some point with token expired exception. **May be it is possible to update this token for this pageIterator and continue scan from point where it failed.**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1. my question "is possible to update this token for this pageIterator and continue scan from point where it failed."

Comment: Other AWS SDKs have the memoize() function will will cache and automatically renew AssumeRole credentials. My "guess" is that you can refresh the credentials from AssumeRole() while scanning.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for your comment. As I said I'm absolutely new in Python and I chose official sdk that is mentioned in aws [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak - You are using the correct SDK. For other languages the AWS SDK has the memoize() function, for some reason the Python  SDK does not. I plan to code up your example this week and test with refreshing credentials. If there is no solution published by then I will post my code as an answer.